# How do I make something Rotate towards mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, mouseevent, mouse

I am trying to solve a question which has been bugging me for a while, can someone explain to me how to make the *red rectangle face/aim towards my mouse and explain to me how it works it would be awesome!!!

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkj9yeyo/2/)**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var player = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
}

drawPlayer = function(something) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.arc(something.x, something.y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();

  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fillRect(something.x, something.y - 10, 50, 20);
  context.restore();
}

update = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
  drawPlayer(player);
}

setInterval(update, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="outline: 1px solid #ccc" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: You want make custom cursor ?

Comment: No I want to make the red rectangle look at the mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `context.translate` to translate coordinates to the center of your player and then `context.rotate` to rotate the rectangle.

To find the angle between the mouse position and the center of the player you can use `Math.atan2` function.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
}

drawPlayer = function(something, angle) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "blue";
    context.arc(something.x, something.y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();

    // save the untranslated context
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    // move the rotation point to the center of the player
    context.translate(something.x, something.y);
    context.rotate(angle);

    context.fillStyle = "red";
    // note that coordinates are translated, 
    // so 0 is player.x and -10 is player.y - 10
    context.fillRect(0, - 10, 50, 20);
    // restore the context to its untranslated state
    context.restore();
}

drawPlayer(player, 0);

document.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    var angle = Math.atan2(e.pageY - player.y, e.pageX - player.x)
    drawPlayer(player, angle);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="outline: 1px solid #ccc" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```