# How do I rotate around a point towards the mouse in PaperJS?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, paperjs

I'm creating a simple game using PaperJS and I'm currently stuck on a small part of it.

In the game, there is a player (just a circle) who has two hands (two smaller circles)

I want the hands to always point towards the mouse position, but I can't figure out the equation needed to do so.

Here's some of the code I have so far, I just need help filling in the blank...

```
view.onMouseMove = function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.point.x;
    var mouseY = event.point.y;

    var rotation = ???

    playerHands.rotate(rotation, view.center)    
}
```

Here is a diagram of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: img]

Comment: I'm not familiar with `paper.js`, but recently I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484522/8629960) regarding rotation towards the mouse. Maybe it will be helpful. I suppose you should write something like this: `var rotation = Math.atan2(mouseY - view.center.y, mouseX - view.center.x) * 180 / Math.PI`

Comment: yes `atan2` is the answer ... to get correct equation how ever we need to knoe your coordinate system (where x,y points and which way angle is increasing) otherwise you would need to play with `+/-` combinations ... You need player position (instead of view center... if they are not the same) and mouse position for this as input .... also you need to know if angle is in `[deg]` or `[rad]` and where is its zero

Answer (score 1):

is really simple:

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    let delta = (event.point - player.position);
    player.rotation = delta.angle+90;
}
```

the idea here is you can use two [Points](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#angle) to do Vector-Geometry.
more in depth descriptions are in the [Vector-Geometry Tutorial](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/geometry/vector-geometry/#rotating-vectors)

there is a `+90` offset needed  to align mouse with top of player as paperjs sees the x axis as 0° for rotation.

i have created a working [example in sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

the above `player.rotation` is only working if the Player `Group` has its `.applyMatrix` set to `false`.
additionally i set the Player-Group `pivot` point to the big circle center at creation:

```
let player = new Group(circle, handleleft, handleright);
player.applyMatrix = false;
player.pivot = circle.bounds.center;
player.position = position;
```